# File or Database for searching zip code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a online shopping cart, at checkout user enters his zipcode.

There are 2 payment methods, cash-on-delivery and net-banking. The courier service ships to only certain areas(identified by zipcode). And the allowed list of zipcodes for COD and Net-Banking differ. (length of list = about 2500 for COD, and about 10,000 for latter)

Should I store these lists in database or a flat file?

For database, I will be querying using `SELECT`, and for file, I can read the entire(or partial) list in array, and then do Binary search on it.

Which one would be faster, considering following points -

1. There is only one courier service now, but in future there will be more, and with different lists of there own. So I need to search in multiple lists.
2. There is mostly read, write would be much less. Also the list should be customisable at later point.

I would have selected Database, but I don't know if it would make things slower, and I don't want to spend time designing database, when a file might be better.

**EDIT:**
Say there are 2 courier companies ABC and DEF.
For *file* I will have 4 files (say) ABC_COD.txt, ABC_net.txt, DEF_COD.txt, DEF_net.txt. So if a customer goes for COD, I search ABC_COD, if not in there, I search DEF_COD and so on. So ok this seems to be costly, but it is also easily extensible.

Now consider database, I will have a table `Allowed_zipcodes`, with five columns : zipcode(int/varchar(6)), ABC_COD(boolean), ABC_net(boolean), DEF_COD(boolean), DEF_net(boolean). If the x company offers cod for y code, the corresponding column has `true`, otherwise `false`.
While this seems good for lookup, adding a company involves a change in schema.

Please consider future changes and design as well.

Comment: do you already use a database in your application?

Comment: @duffy356: Yes, and we are using Magento framework for shopping cart.

Comment: How about zip code ranges? e.g. 2003 through 2199 is one area with the same delivery details.. Your database model should resemble this, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I think you should look at the magenta framework, isn't it already in some of the packages?

But if you want to do it yourself: Just to give you a starting point on the database model:

```
carrier
        id(int) | name (varchar)

zipcodes
        start(int) | end(int) | carrier(fk::carrier.id)
```

For instance:

```
carrier
        1 | UPS
        2 | fedex

zipcodes
        1000 | 1199 | 2
        1000 | 1099 | 1
```

Querying your zipcode and available carriers:

```
SELECT carrier.name 
FROM zipcodes 
LEFT JOIN carrier ON zip codes.carrier = carrier.id
WHERE
   zipcodes.end >= :code
AND
   zipcodes.start <= :code
```

Comment: Your idea seems good! But I have yet to get the list from Courier company. Will have to see if it is sparse or dense. I would just have 2 tables for zipcodes, like cod_zipcodes and net_zipcodes. Nice and extensible.

Comment: When you have two exactly the same tables (cod_zipcodes and net_zipcodes) you should really consider to merge them; it's exactly the same data spread over two tables... For instance: i want to know what delivery method is available in 9999 -> then in your setup you'll have to query two tables and join them; What if you want to add a third carrier? Another table? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: You didn't get my point. cod and net banking are 2 payment methods. A customer will choose any one of them. I have to query only one table, and there is no need to join. If it is COD i query cod_zipcodes. And if there is third or more carrier, I just add there ranges in the 2 table, and in `carrier` of course.

Comment: Aaah sorry, I misunderstood/misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 3):

Database, without any hint of a doubt. More logical, and more scalable.