# Range vs list of zip codes for lookup?

Tags: mysql, sql

For a shopping cart, I want to build a database of zip codes, where my carrier can ship.

I might have several carriers, so I am looking for a flexible solution. And there are 2 payment methods - COD(cash) and prepaid(net-banking).

The list of shipping zipcodes from one of the carrier has 2,775 entries for COD method, and 4,139 entries for prepaid payment.

Design #1 (Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11152714/558094))

I convert the straight list to ranges (like {1,2,3,5,8,9} => {(1,3), (5,5), (8,9)}), and have schema -

```
carrier
        id(int) | name (varchar)

cod_zipcodes
        start(int) | end(int) | carrier(fk::carrier.id)

prepaid_zipcodes
        start(int) | end(int) | carrier(fk::carrier.id)
```

On converting to ranges the prepaid zipcodes shrunk to 1,593(38%) and cod zipcodes shrunk to 842(30%).

Design #2

```
cod_zipcodes
    zipcode(int)

prepaid_zipcodes
    zipcode(int)
```

Basically this design just has the list as it is. If there are multiple carriers I merge the list. So I lose the information which carrier has shipment for a particular zip code. But this is not a problem (But if it is sorted out, that's not a problem either!). I just want to lookup the database, that the zipcode entered by customer is in our allowed list.

I have limited experience with live databases. Please indicate which design is better, or suggest your own.

Thanks!

Comment: Being that `1` isn't a zip-code, do you have a table of zip-codes?  And that `1` is actually just a key to that table?  If so, is that zip-code table permanently fixed or can zip-codes be added or removed from that table?  And I assume that the id id auto_increment, which would mean that a new zip-code doesn't get inserted with an id close to zip-codes that are similar to it?

Comment: @Dems: Currently I just have 2 text files, with zip codes, one on each line. In the question I just gave example to show how I am building ranges. The zip-code list for a carrier might change, but infrequently. But then we may add or switch the carriers, again it should be rare. yes the id in design 1 is auto increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first design is probably the most compact; it can be optimized by adding a spanning index over `start` and `end`. You can also combine both payment types like so:

```
zipcodes
    start(int) | end(int) | carrier(fk::carried.id) | cod (0, 1) | prepaid (0, 1)
```

*The `carrier` field is optional, though you could use it later when you need to update one carrier's zip code ranges.*

Don't try to be smart and merge ranges together based on whether `cod` and `prepaid` is available; you can enter multiple ranges with a different carrier and payment type availability. To query them you would use:

```
SELECT COUNT(cod), COUNT(prepaid) 
FROM zipcodes 
WHERE start <= :start AND :end <= end
```

This will give a single row containing the availability of `cod` and/or `prepaid` for a particular zip code (even though it may match more than one database row.

When a carrier changes their zip code ranges and payment availability, the easiest is to delete all rows for that carrier and repopulate (using a table lock); and if you decide to keep that database field, this is pretty easy for you.

---

Your second design looks more like how you receive the zipcode list from the carriers and management is more simplified. I would again put them into one table though:

```
zipcodes
    zipcode | cod (0, 1) | prepaid(0, 1)
```

By choosing `ENUM` datatype you can get pretty good data compression as well. Updating this table when a carrier changes their delivery data is less trivial, because the `carrier` field is missing, so that means you have to eitherwrite a script that detects the addition, deletion and updates of a particular zip code or start over completely with both carrier data.

---

If updates are rare and you don't mind taking the whole table down when it does happen, I would recommend the second option. By adding `cod` and `prepaid` types in each row rather than two separate tables you can use a primary key for faster lookups compared to the range solution.

If you like flexibility and the fact that you can tell which carrier is supported on a particular range I would go for the first option; the index is still fast enough for most cases and the table size is likely comparably with the second option.

Comment: Your first idea will potentially use more space than using two tables.  *(Not in all case, but possibly in some.)*  But merging potentially unrelated range you will potentially fragment all the ranges into much smaller pieces.  `COD{2-4}` plus `PRE{1-2}` plus `PRE{4-5}` => 5 different distinct range of one zipcode each.

Comment: @Dems yeah that's possible, guess the OP knows the data better than us, so I hope to get some feedback from him/her as well :)

Comment: @Jack: +1 Here you can access straight list as well as ranges for COD : https://www.box.com/s/f60662e3b5042c965673. My senior is in favor of  2nd solution. So maybe merging 2 tables will be okay(?). I am not sure about this though.

Comment: @VinayakGarg I've updated my answer to give a clearer reasoning :)